# What does "base of exploration" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> My father moved with all his kids to Beijing because he wanted to use it as a base of exploration.

What does "base of exploration" mean?

Comment: What does your research into _base_ and _exploration_ suggest to you and what doubts do you still have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite literally: 'base' is used here in a sense of 'home', 'starting point' to where you always return, in this case after exploring something (e.g. the rest of China, or life in general).

> 4a : the starting point or line for an action or undertaking
> // plans to make this city his *base* of operation

(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/base))